# Can you change raid type on an active server?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm

I was just dabbling with a few different raid types recently for some performance testing and I was hoping someone could answer this question for the sake of knowledge.

Is it possible to change the Raid type on an active configuration without reloading the entire OS on the server? In regards to Linux.

Such as switching from Raid 1 to Raid 5 and adding an additional drive as required. Is this at all possible?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It depends entirely on the RAID controller, but you did not specify which one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely possible, though it depends on how you've implemented RAID.

If you're using Linux software RAID (e.g. mdadm), live RAID type conversions are definitely possible.

If you're using hardware RAID in a server, *most* modern RAID controllers support live RAID type conversions... Though you'd want to check the user manual for the particular model to find out for sure, and get specifics about how to do so.

How have you implemented RAID? Specifying hardware platform and Linux distribution details would be good (and really should have been in your initial question, FYI).

Answer (score 0):

As above with hardware RAID it really depends on the RAID card and the options it supports.

Whatever you do though if you start messing around with the RAID config make sure you have a verified backup just in case it goes wrong.